# Encrypting streaming data from Python requests to boto storage

Tags: python, encryption, stream, python-requests, google-cloud-storage

I am using Python requests to download a file then immediately upload it to storage via boto. The download is streamed directly into boto to avoid storing the file locally. I would like to add an intermediate step to encrypt the stream after it is downloaded but before it is uploaded.

Note that this is uploading into Google Cloud Storage, which supports streaming uploads.

```
import boto
import gcs_oauth2_boto_plugin
import requests

url = 'https://www.example.com/file.tar.gz'

r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

filename = 'file.tar.gz'
uri = boto.storage_uri(filename, 'gs')
uri.new_key().set_contents_from_stream(r.raw)
```

What is the best way to iterate through the stream and encrypt it, before passing it through to set_contents_from_stream()? Ideally I would be using a standardised encryption library, not having to implement any of the encryption code myself.

Answer (score 0):

python does not offer builtin encyption, but there are
plenty of good packages you can use. The python website
recommends pycrypto http://www.pycrypto.org.  Here's a
sample of how you could use it in your application

```
import boto
import gcs_oauth2_boto_plugin
import requests
from Crypto.Cipher import DES

url = 'https://www.example.com/file.tar.gz'

r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

obj = DES.new("mysecretkey", DES.MODE_ECB)
encrypted_contents = obj.encrypt(r.raw)

filename = 'file.tar.gz'
uri = boto.storage_uri(filename, 'gs')
uri.new_key().set_contents_from_stream(encryped_contents)
```

Comment: Will that actually work? r.raw is a streaming object - can the Crypto encrypt() method handle that properly, and then pass it as a stream to set_contents_from_stream()?

Comment: I'm not sure ... you'll need to experiment. As I said, python offers no native mechanisms for encryption, and pycrypto is a good place to start. Worst case, you may need to temporarily stream it to disk, then upload to boto storage.  If you absolutely cannot afford the local space, you could probably craft your own middle ware than incrementally encrypts and uploads in chunks. Of course if you have enough RAM, you could also just suck everything into memory and upload from there. Sorry I can't be of more help, but not familiar w/ boto.